# Finding Objects Most Similar to Other Objects as a "Linear Combination"

Tags: normed-spaces, data-analysis

I have a small collection of objects, $\{o_i\}_{i=1}^{20},$ that have several properties (all quantitative, or can be made to be quantitative) that differ among themselves. So $o_1$ has, say, $10$ properties, $\{p_{1j}\}_{j=1}^{10},$ and something similar for the other $19$ objects. I have $5$ more objects that are of the same general kind as the original $20,$ but have yet different properties. Unfortunately, these properties are not even the same categories among all $25$ total objects. Some of the properties are common to all the objects, and some are not.

There is one important property, I'll call "usage", that is common to all $25$ objects. We'll let the usage of object $i$ be written as $u_i$. Note that $u_i\ge 0\;\forall\,i.$

What I would like to do is find a way to write each of the $5$ new usages as a linear combination of the $20$ original object usages, with objects among the $20$ that are more similar contributing more.

For example, let's take one of the new objects, $o_{21}$. I would like to write
$$u_{21}=\sum_{i=1}^{20}a_i u_i,\qquad 0\le a_i\le 1\;\forall\,i,\qquad \text{s.t.}\;\sum_{i=1}^{20}a_i=1.$$
Now suppose that $o_7$ was the most similar to $o_{21}:$ then $a_7$ should be larger than all the other $a_{i}$'s. It is ***not*** important that this "linear combination" allow me to predict the properties of $o_{21}.$ It's only important that $\sum_{i=1}^{20}a_i=1$ and that objects more similar to $o_{21}$ have correspondingly larger $a_i$'s.

**The target variables** here are, for each of the $5$ new objects, the $a_i$'s that satisfy the above criteria. The $u_i$ are known for the $20$ original objects, and unknown for the $5$ new objects, so the $u_i$ are also target variables for the new objects. However, as knowing the $a_i$ will determine the $u_i$ for the new objects, the immediate goal for this question is to find the $a_i$'s.

Now it's not too difficult to find out which of the $20$ original objects are "closest" to, say, $o_{21}:$ normalize the common quantitative categories, drop the ones not common to all, and use the Euclidean distance norm. (I have no *a priori* notion of which properties might be more important than others, so I'd rather treat them all on an equal footing.) If I divided each of these distances by the sum total of all the distances, I would get the opposite of what I want: the "closer" objects would have correspondingly smaller $a_i$'s.

So it comes down to this question: what sort of function would be good to switch this around, so that the closer objects get larger $a_i$'s? Subtract each distance from the maximum distance and then normalize?

Comment: The first problem that I can see here is that there's no reason why your original objects should span the vector space of properties.

Comment: That's unimportant in my application. This application is kind of like Natural Language Processing, e.g., if I'm wanting to find a word most similar to another in meaning. In a situation like that, it's not important if the set of words you have to work with spans the space of all meanings. You just want the closest one. In this case, I don't want to lose the information that the objects farther away give me, hence the linear combination. I could just go with the closest, but in this application, I think the linear combination gives me a bit more finesse.

Comment: It isn't, though: the very first thing that you do is write your new object as a linear combination of the old ones. If the old objects don't span, how can you know that's even possible?

Comment: You're quite right; I already know it's not possible in any exact sense. The "linear combination" is only there as a way of expressing the idea that $o_{21}$ is like all these $20$ objects, but it's more like $o_7$ than $o_9,$ and it's more like $o_{10}$ than $o_{3}$.

Comment: Perhaps, then, you could instead edit the question to say what you mean. Because right now, it's essentially impossible to answer.

Comment: I've added the "usage" variable to be more clear as to what I want. Since all the usages are scalars, it's not even really about spanning any sort of space. Does that clarify?

Comment: The properties have now entirely dissappeared: since you're now only comparing scalars, the answer is trivial: the closest is the one such that $|u_i - u_{21}|$ is minimised. I'm very sure that this isn't what you want, though.

Comment: The other properties are the criteria by which I determine which objects are closest to the new ones, so I wouldn't say they've disappeared at all.

Comment: Then what are the $u_i$ doing?

Comment: The $u_i$ are sort of my end goal here. I want to put out a reasonable value of $u_i$ for each of the $5$ new objects based on how close they are (as measured by the other properties) to the original $20$. The $u_i$ for the original $20$ are known.

Comment: As a boring comment, I think that guys from statistical or machine learning communities might give you a better advice on your question. There might be already some way to solve your problem but maybe with a different tools. Sorry if you've already asked this question in their communities and this comment is useless :)

Comment: @Evgeny: Yeah, I thought of that, but it seemed to me that the problem had a more mathematical structure to it, and so I thought it appropriate here.